# Optimizacion para comprimir ficheros en un ZIP con java

Tags: java, zip, jar

Estoy utilizando el siguiente metodo para comprimir ficheros en un zip

```
public static void ComprensionArchivos(String nombreZip, List<File> listaFicheros ) throws ECIException {
        
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(nombreZip);
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            
            
            for (File file : listaFicheros) {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(file.getName());
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                
                byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                int longitud;
                
                while((longitud = fis.read(bytes)) >=0) {
                    zos.write(bytes, 0, longitud);
                }
                zos.flush();
                fis.close();
            }
            
            zos.close();
            fos.close();            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Error para comprimir en zip la lista de ficheros. Motivo:" + e.getMessage());
            throw new ECIException(ECIError.E004);
        }
```

Donde nombreZip es la ruta donde estará ubicado el fichero zip (por ejemplo "C:\carpetaZip\ficheroZip.zip")

Este método está en una clase de una aplicación java que es un ejecutable jar. Dicho jar es ejecutado manualmente mediante un bat o esta programado que se ejecute a las 00:30 de cada día.

El problema es que si en List listaFicheros hay sólo 10 ficheros se ejecuta bien pero si son 250 ficheros tarda demasiado tiempo. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de optimizar el tiempo de comprimir para que tarde lo menos posible. Aclaro que List listaFicheros tiene ficheros con extensión .txt y .pdf.

Cualquier duda o aclaración decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que te servirá revisar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091788/how-to-create-a-zip-file-in-java) en especial la respuesta que habla del [ZipFileSystemProvider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html).

Comment: ¿Se comprimen todos los archivos de la carpeta? Una cosa que podrías hacer es ejecutar desde java el comando [Jar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html). No estoy seguro, pero tal vez te ayude delegarle el trabajo al S.O. en vez de a tu programa

Comment: Sí, se nos han comprimido 300 ficheros en una hora

Comment: puede intentar crear un threadpool CONTROLADO, por ejemplo, "while threadcount <= 20 { new thread ... {zip }}". La cantidad de threads que puede abrir dependerá de su procesador y memoria, si coloca demasiados threads  al mismo tiempo, es posible que no sea efectivo.